# Infer values from object

Tags: typescript

How do I infer all values from an object like this…

```
const fruits = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana'
};
```

…so that I get this?

```
type fruitValues = 'apple' | 'banana';
```

(I believe I'm looking for the equivalent of `$Values<T>` in Flow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can infer the type from the object, but the object has already been inferred to hold only `string` properties.  That is, the types `"apple"` and `"banana"` have been *widened* to `string`, as mentioned in [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676#issue-83725748), because they are non-`readonly` properties.

```
const fruits = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana'
};

type FruitValues = (typeof fruits)[keyof typeof fruits]; // string
```

So the above `FruitValues` is not what you want.  If you want to get closer, you need to prevent that widening.  One way is to use redundant but self-contained [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const fruits = {
  a: 'apple' as 'apple',
  b: 'banana' as 'banana'
};

type FruitValues = (typeof fruits)[keyof typeof fruits]; // "apple" | "banana"
```

Another way is to make a helper function that infers narrower types:

```
// put in a library somewhere
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
const narrowObj = <V extends Narrowable, T extends { [k: string]: V }>(t: T) => t;

const fruits = narrowObj({
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana'
})

type FruitValues = (typeof fruits)[keyof typeof fruits]; // "apple" | "banana"
```

Finally, once [TypeScript 3.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#34-march-2019) lands there will be [`const` contexts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) which will infer the narrowest possible type (including making all the properties `readonly` which you might not want), like this:

```
const fruits = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana'
} as const; // requires TS3.4+

type FruitValues = (typeof fruits)[keyof typeof fruits]; // "apple" | "banana"
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: fantastic! i've been trying to find this for ages!